# How to hide all drawings in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button and I want it to be able to hide all shapes with as few lines as possible. I would prefer not to have to hide each drawing individually. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer. Group all your drawings first. Then just hide the visibility as shown.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 7")).Visible = False
```